# Confusion on pseudo-elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I need to drop Cap the first letter in the first article only but not sure how to do that.  I can do it for every paragraph but not sure how to do it for only one paragraph.

```
/* First Line and Drop Cap Styles */

article::first-line {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font: small-caps;
}

article::first-letter {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: serif;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `p:first-of-type` on the article. That would select the first paragraph only.

w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp

Comment: Thank you.  I had originally tried that and it didn't work, but I looked it over, tried it again, and now it finally works.

Comment: Then please approve the answer so others can see it works.